# bsts package installation error

Tags: r, package, failed-installation

I'm receving following error when trying to install `bsts` package in R:

```
bsts.cc:71:5: error: 'clock_t' was not declared in this scope
     clock_t start_time = clock();
     ^
bsts.cc:72:29: error: 'CLOCKS_PER_SEC' was not declared in this scope
     double time_threshold = CLOCKS_PER_SEC * timeout_threshold_seconds;
                             ^
bsts.cc:82:17: error: expected ';' before 'current_time'
         clock_t current_time = clock();
                 ^
bsts.cc:83:13: error: 'current_time' was not declared in this scope
         if (current_time - start_time > time_threshold) {
             ^
bsts.cc:83:28: error: 'start_time' was not declared in this scope
         if (current_time - start_time > time_threshold) {
                            ^
make: *** [bsts.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.0/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)' SHLIB="bsts.dll" OBJECTS="aggregate_time_series.o bsts.o mixed_frequency.o model_manager.o state_space_gaussian_model_manager.o state_space_logit_model_manager.o state_space_poisson_model_manager.o state_space_regression_model_manager.o state_space_student_model_manager.o utils.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'bsts'
```

I have tried following methods:

1. `devtools::install_github('cran/bsts')`
2. Straight from R Studio, this will download .tar file and I receive same error, when trying to install that.

[install error of bsts package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076967/install-error-of-bsts-package-in-r) had similar problem, but `BOOM` and `BoomSpikeSlab` was correctly installed for me. I can provide more details from error, if needed. How can I get that package installed?

My session.info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Finnish_Finland.1252  LC_CTYPE=Finnish_Finland.1252    LC_MONETARY=Finnish_Finland.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                    
[5] LC_TIME=Finnish_Finland.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.11.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.1.0    R6_2.1.2      tools_3.3.0   withr_1.0.1   curl_0.9.7    memoise_1.0.0 git2r_0.15.0  digest_0.6.9
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will write to package maintainer.

Comment: I tried to install it using Rstudio on Mac and windows, it worked fine on the mac, but on windows it would not work because my R was not the right version.

Comment: not sure why this question got downvoted... it's a clear question with the necessary information provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144856/) -- in essence, it is 'operator error' because *the package does not come with a Windows binary from CRAN* which is usually a *very strong* indication that it does not build on Windows.

CRAN is not in habit of not building on Windows out of spite---the site in Dortmund operated by Uwe Ligges usually builds *everything* that can reasonably be built.  I suspect an underlying technical issue.

Comment: You are correct, that looks like same problem as I have. Will have to wait that maintainers fix it. Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Win 10 (64 bit), latest R and R Studio and Rtools (v33) installed. Strangely, I did manage to install it on another Win 10 computer (same R version), so I'm not sure what's wrong in this case.

Comment: It turns out that on the other computer (see comment above) version 0.6.2. was installed (bsts), which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can install the previous version (0.6.2.) on Windows:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/bsts_0.6.2.zip", 
                  repos = NULL, type = "local")
```